# Wordpress multiple pages to show posts

Tags: wordpress, templates

I don't have any code or pages to show yet so I'll just have to describe my question.

I have a group of post in Wordpress, no categories or taxnomoy yet.

On my home page I have a 'View all posts' link that is linked to a view_all_post.php page.

On the view_all_posts.php page I have a simple loop that shows all the posts.

I only want to show 10 posts on the view_all_posts.php page and have the rest of the posts on the next page that will be linked on the view_all_posts page.

So the view_all_posts will show 10 post and then have links to show the next page with the rest of the links on, that will have links to the next page if there are more posts to show.

I know how to limit the number of post - post_per_page

My problem is how to create the extra pages with the rest of the posts.

I'm sure I don't create another view_all_post page because I don't know how many post there will be and so it won't be dynamic.

Is there a template page I should be using like single.php to show actual posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, You need pagination of `posts` in word-press. Check very useful function from Word press.

```
<?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
```

[See Complete Refrence](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Answer (score 0):

You have not made provision for pagination, which is integral for what you want to do. You should go and have a look at how to construct a custom query and how to make use of the pagination parameters in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

You will also need to go and have a look at [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and [`previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) which is used to navigate your pages to the next/previous set of posts. This is very simple navigation links. There are more sophisticated pagination functions out there, it is just a matter of searching with google.

It is important that you know and understand how the `next_posts_link` is used in custom queries work, otherwise your pagination won't work at all

Something like this will do the trick. But you need to go and read the links I've provided so that you understand what I've had done

```
<?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$allposts_args  = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $allposts_loop = new WP_Query($allposts_args);

        if($allposts_loop->have_posts()):
            while($allposts_loop->have_posts()):
                $allposts_loop->the_post();

    ?>

<---YOUR LOOP--->

           endwhile;

       // next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
       next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $allposts_loop->max_num_pages );
       previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );

wp_reset_postdata(); 

endif;
```

You should also have a look at [Debugging Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) when you are developing a theme. You should first end your while statement before you end your if statement, not the other way around. And `wp_reset_postdata();` should be called before your `endif` statement